# Transferring my existing draw something game data to a new phone

Tags: draw-something

I've been playing draw somwthing for a little while now and have collected coins, colors, etc. but I've just replaced my old Galaxy S for a newer Galaxy S2 Skyrocket and was wondering if I can continue playing on my new phone or if I have to manually transfer my data over.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As you have probably discovered by now, your games, colors, and coins are associated with your account rather the device on which you play. All you need to do is download Draw Something to your Skyrocket and log in; you should then be able to continue your existing games, use previously-purchased colors, and so on.

This also applies if you have multiple devices on which you can play Draw Something: you should be able to play on any device as long as you log in to the same account on each one.